# Are there canonical Sanskrit scriptures besides various Ramayanas which relate events involving Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama

In particular, do Puranas have additional material involving Rama, not counting different versions of events in Valmiki Ramayana?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there were but unfortunately at present, it's extinct.
For example

**1)brihadvishnu puran
2)shuka up-puran
3) Ramayan mahatmya of parashar up-puran**

Then there are other scriptures of narad pancharatra which are also extinct

Comment: If these are extinct now, how did you know that they existed at one point ?

Comment: Because acharyas of shri Ramanand sampradaye have quoted in their works

Comment: In that case, it would be pertinent of you to name those Ramanandi works that have quoted them & also the quotes.

Comment: Ram navratan saar sangrah, ram paratvam, sita ram naam Pratap prakash, upasana Trey siddhant, and many more